# How to scroll an element to the center of the screen

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

```
driver.get(
    "http://www.uitestingplayground.com/scrollbars")
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", driver.find_element_by_id("hidingButton"))
```

I am trying to scroll the hode button into center of the  element but the vertical scroll bar is not properly at center.

Is there any way to scroll it to the center ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.get(
    "http://www.uitestingplayground.com/scrollbars")
time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].scrollIntoView({'block':'center','inline':'center'})", driver.find_element_by_id("hidingButton"))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

use inline and block options

Comment: it worked :) thank you